# (f)lex can you have multiple expressions in one state?

Tags: state, lex, expression, flex-lexer

is it possible to have multiple expression in one state that are similar? I was hoping to group together a few expressions to make life easy for myself. i want to do something similar below but its not working and only recognise the 1st expr and although it does match the expr it doesnt save into the array using yytext. im guessing im doing something wrong so any help would be appreciated.Thanks

```
<some_state>"Milk;" |
"Honey;"    |
"Cinnamon;" |
"Cardamon;" |
"Rum;"      |
"Brandy;"   |
"Whiskey;"  |
"Aquavit;"  |
"Kahula;"   { printf("Example"); array[i].addition = yytext;BEGIN(amount_state);}
```

Comment: Is this a question about Adobe Flex?  Or Gnu-Flex?  If about Adobe Flex it makes absolutely no sense to me.

Comment: sorry its about GNU Flex its got the wrong tag on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `flex` is allowed, you can use start condition scope like the following:

```
<some_state>{
"Milk;"         |
"Honey;"        |
...             |
"Kahula;"       { printf("Example"); ... }
}
```

If only `AT&T lex` is allowed, unfortunately this may be invalid...

Comment: yes im using GNU Flex and is no working i missed the open parenthesis and should have had it on a new line thank you. I can print the expr found in the printf statement but for some reason it wont save it in to my array using an_array[i] = yytext; method. Have you any ideas as to why? Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this question but i have decided to implement it a different way due to yytext saving the whole string rather than the expr. Thanks